# Getting an error when intry to load a dataframe

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[Getting a syntax error and not sure why. Trying to loadca dataframe. Please can someone help. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKDci.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting started with programming, jupyter can be counter intuitive at some points, I assume that's not your first cell in the notebook, so be sure to run the previous ones where the definition for titanic_df/titanic_csv is loaded.

The error you are getting says NameError, not SyntaxError, and it is informing you that a variable called titanic_csv does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I am new to programming. I am kinda stuck now, don't know what else to do. Might have to leave it till monday and show to my tutor for help. Thanks alot for making out time to respond.

Comment: Don't you have previous cells in the notebook to run?

Comment: I do. Please what do I do to the previous cell?

Comment: Execute them before executing the cell you sent the screenshot of

Comment: Yeah I did that. The first cell I imported a csv file of the titanic.

Comment: are you assigning ```titanic_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)```

Comment: Yeah I am trying to import the particular data from the csv file and thsts when I get the error

Comment: You need to provide more context on the code then

Comment: I wish I can show you the whole code

Comment: Copy all the cells of code into only one cell, orderly, and then paste the code in your question instead of the image